# Open a waiting modal and redirect to a page

Tags: bootstrap-modal

With the same hyper link, I want to open a waiting Modal (Boostrap 4) and when this is open, I want a redirection to the new page.

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Config" asp-controller="GeneralSettings" asp-action="Index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#waitModal">@Localizer["GeneralSettings"]</a>

<div class="modal" id="waitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="waitModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addConfiguration">Please Wait ...</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              Description
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="text-center">
                <img src="~/images/pleaseWait.gif" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this, I guess what you need and $ (window) .load () on the destination page.
On the landing page open the "modal" first of all and then, by loading the page completely using $ (window) .load (), destroy the "modal"